# method Name execute This statement does not declare an OUT parameter. Use { ?= call ... } to declare one

Tags: java, oracle, postgresql, weblogic, amazon-aurora

I had migrated database from Oracle to AWS Aurora PostgreSQL. I saw that all the packages are migrated as Function in PostgreSQL. I used AWS SCT for the Oracle schema conversion to postgreSQL. **Java** is the application middleware.

for example,
A package and associated stored proc in Oracle `pk_audit.sp_get_audit` converted to postgreSQL as `pk_audit$sp_get_audit` with a `$` symbol.

When I run the web application, I'm getting an error like **method Name execute This statement does not declare an OUT parameter. Use { ?= call ... } to declare one** .

I don't have access to the application, but App team provided weblogic log. It says,

`Method Name execute org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
This statement does not declare an OUT parameter.Use { ?= call ... } to declare one.
org.postgresql.jdbc.PgCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(PgCallableStatement.java:205)     weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.CallableStatement_org_postgresql_jdbc_PgCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(Unknown Source`

package name specified in the Java code is `pk_audit.sp_get_audit`
Renamed the Postgres function `pk_audit$sp_get_audit` to `pk_audit.sp_get_audit` still facing the issue.

Is there anything I need to do in PostgreSQL DB ? 
I need advise and help,Thanks.

Comment: Then your app team has to solve the problem alone. Without the code that causes the error, we cannot help you.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe.  Okay. how can I update pk_audit$sp_get_audit to pk_audit.sp_get_audit this format in a single shot ?

Comment: `ALTER FUNCTION` or `ALTER PROCEDURE`, depending on what it is.

Comment: I want to keep it as function, but the problem is `$` in the procedure. I need to replace $ to '.' (dot)  in all the user defined functions. like pk_audit.sp_get_audit

Comment: Yes, `ALTER FUNCTION ... RENAME TO ...`.

Comment: `update  pg_proc pr
set  proname = replace(pr.proname, '$', '.')
From  pg_proc p
left join pg_namespace n on p.pronamespace = n.oid
where n.nspname = 'schema_name'
and p.proname = ' pk_audit.sp_get_audit' ;` which is giving permission denied for the relation pg_proc .

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I've 1500 function in the database, Can i do it in a single update query ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210806/discussion-between-aan-anna-philip-and-laurenz-albe).

Comment: No. And that has nothing to do with this question. Ask a new one. And have a look at `psql`'s `\gexec`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Posted new question [new_qus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60996449/naming-issues-on-oracle-packages-conversion-to-postgresql-using-aws-sct-tool)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented in [`CallableStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html), the JDBC syntax for calling stored procedures is one of these

```
{call ProcedureName(?, ...)}

{? = call FunctionName(?, ...)}
```

Any of the parameters can be OUT parameters. The return value is of course a type of OUT parameter.

So, if you had a stored procedure with 2 parameters and the second parameter was an OUT parameter, you would code it as:

```
String sql = "{call MyProcedure(?, ?)}";
try (CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(sql)) {
    stmt.setInt(1, p1);
    stmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
    ...
}
```

If that same procedure is converted into a function, you would code it as:

```
String sql = "{? = call MyFunction(?)}";
try (CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(sql)) {
    stmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
    stmt.setInt(2, p1);
    ...
}
```

If you cannot change the Java code making the call, you need to convert your functions back to procedures.

Comment: Note that Postgres supports procedures only from [version 11](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createprocedure.html) onwards, so you need at least Aurora [version 3.0](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Updates.20180305.html), or stick to functions.